# Very flexible and durable wires?

Tags: wiring

I'm thinking of something akin to transforming clothes into LED displays. (Not quite, but close enough.) Lots and lots of small beads (and fewer larger beads) embedded into the fabric and connected with wires.

Google gives me lots of images for "LED clothes", but the problem is, they all look like costumes that require very delicate handling. What I want to achieve is something you could, say, go to bed in regularly, and have it still working after months of such abuse. The fabric itself should take most of the stress, but it still sounds like it would be rough on the wires.

Is there any kind of wire flexible and durable enough to survive that?

Comment: does cotton stretch? does polyester? so must the wires?

Comment: There is a kind of wire I've used, made out of at least 19 strands (but more is better.) The wire strands are silver and I've usually found it as military surplus, though I'm sure it can be bought outright. I believe I saw something with 39 strands, at the time, but I'm not certain. Regardless, what I've used has been very robust to flexing and bending with normal body motions and is still in use after many years. There sheathing is multiplayer and exceptionally well designed, too. I hadn't even realized it existed until I looked around with a similar question in mind. Just FYI.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf  A zigzag stitch, for example, may allow for stretch in the textile when using wire as a thread.

Answer (score 0):

Conductive thread is readily available. There may be several materials and formulations used to make it. At least some of the available thread is very flexible, but you will need to investigate to determine how difficult it will be to deal with the higher resistivity compared to more conventional wire.

Conductive thread may not be as durable the thread used to make conventional clothing fabric. In regular fabric, quite a few threads can break before the clothing would be considered "worn out."

Making reliable connections may also be problematic. You will need to investigate solder ability or the feasibility, size, cost and reliability of other connection methods.

Your search for "LED clothing" should turn up some reports describing how others have handled the various design problems.